# How to set type to an argument of function in polyml?

Tags: smlnj, ml

I want to overide the type detection of ml and want the argument to be allowed type as specified.

Comment: Whenever someone tries to do this, a puppy dies.

Comment: Indeed.  Standard ML is unpopular for a reason: it excludes such non-sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use

```
Unsafe.cast
```

, which has type `'a -> 'b`.

You should never use this -- if you think you need to, you probably should instead consider whether what you're trying to do is really a good idea. It's called unsafe for a reason.